# How can I merge webm and wav file without using FFMpeg lib in PHP shared hosting?

Tags: php, audio, video, youtube, webrtc

I want to merge webm video with a WAV audio file. Is there any way to do that in shared php hosting?

My final target is:

> I have two files (Webm & WAV). I want to upload a video into youtube
>   programmatically.  But my audio & video file are different. I have
>   only shared PHP server so I can't use FFMpeg or node.js to merge. So
>   Is there any way to do this?

**Please advice me.**

Comment: Merging (muxing) audio/video is very difficult job. It's not easy even with ffmpeg.

Comment: @9dan thanks for your comment. I know it is not easy. But I just want to know, is there any way or not..